# Business Intelligence Software pros and cons (sharepoint, microstrategy)

Tags: database-design, business-intelligence

my management are starting to make noises about data mining and business intelligence so I thought I'd try to get ahead of them to guide any decisions. Currently they are talking about using MS Sharepoint or Microstrategy software but there seems to be a lot of other BI applications available. If you've worked with any please can you let me know what you think, particularly the downsides of the product you know.

I'd also be interested in any thoughts/links about the design of data warehouses. I'm familiar with std SQL databases but what are these 'cubes'.

I expect we'll get expert help when needed but beginnings are delicate times and I'd like to be more familiar with the subject before irrevocable decisions are made.

Thanks,
Patrick

**EDIT:** I don't really know our requirements. Our parent company is making some money out of BI and for various reasons we may be better positioned to take advantage of this market. Our role (the in house developers) is likely to be writing a few reports once the data warehouse is in place. So what tools will be easiest to use to develop reports? Any background knowledge I can pick up to help evaluate/understand propositions from people we bring in to do the hard stuff would also be useful and interesting (I'm scouring the web but a few links from those who already know the field would speed things along).

Comment: Well, the MS end of the market is not the Enterprise end, if your co is stuck with MS, then you are dealing with s/w and platforms that are about 15 years behind the rest of the world; about one tenth the stability and quality; and that force the purchase of lots more little boxes which require lots more windoze licences. Which is why MS is not a player in the BI or data warehouse space. Therefore, the question is, do you want answers limited to MS or generally for BI/DW ?

Comment: You seem to work in MS environment. Do you have SQL server 2005/2008/2010 standard or enterprise in the house?

Comment: We are primarily MS but have used other products before when there was a good reason for doing so. We use SQL 2008 at the moment but we're at the beginning here so if I can come up with good reasons to use something else then I may be able to swing it.

Comment: You should have a look at QlikView. For your first steps you can use the PersonalEdition for free. When you are familar with SQL you should be able to create your first dashbords (with KPIs...) wihtin a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call Sharepoint a business intelligence or data mining application. It's simply a web publishing tool, Microsoft's proprietary answer to Wordpress/Drupal/Mediawiki. I don't have much experience with it, but [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) is a better example of a business intelligence application.

Comment: God I hate Pentaho... they constantly spam me, tried to unsubscribe, it never worked, so I have added them to the corporate spam-minder

Comment: God I hate people who post non-technical nonsense on technical websites.

Comment: You can't compare Sharepoint to Wordpress/etc, it is lot of more powerful than just a "web publishing tool".

Answer (score 2):

Your question is **FAR** too big for SO.

- Datawarehousing is an entire career... asking for our "thoughts" won't be productive.
- Cubes are a complete database technology, it's like asking what are these 'compilers'.
- BI is an entire career. It is as nuanced and complex as web design or any other speciality.

I totally appreciate your proactive nature but you're really asked for 10 years of experience in an hour.

What I would **strongly** suggest reading the [The Data Warehouse Lifecycle Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471255475)

This covers all decisions in creating a DW which is the heart of any good BI implementation.

**Edit**

While your developing a BI strategy, you'll be making a lot of decisions. Some of the least among them is toolset. While some have suggested that Microsoft is "behind", and I'm counted squarely as not a fan of M$, it works just fine for a vast majority of business in the world. If you're not Fortune 1000, shelling out Millions for Microstrategy may be overkill. But either way these decisions pale in comparison to the ones you'll make about what business impact your BI should accomplish, will you build a Kimball style DWH or an Enterprise Data Warehouse... etc.

### Biased Opinion here

Don't fall for anyone selling Data Federation BI. the toughest part about BI is getting a complete understanding of what the data is and conforming it so it can be reported coherently. That is impossible to achieve by ONLY building a metadata layer.

Comment: Hi Stephanie, thanks for the reply. We understand that we're out of our depth and will (I hope) bring in outside expertise when required (I expect my role will be developing reports, not designing the dw). I guess I shouldn't have asked about data warehousing it just seemed interesting. At this stage management is focusing on tool sets (and asking me to help evaluate them) and I want to get the right ones in place. Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: That's kinda the thing. Starting at the tool choice is the wrong order. You're walking into Home Depot buying a drill and then determining what the project is. In some ways, a lot of the report writing tools are all the same. Invite them to do demos. After the third one you'll be able to do the fourth one on your own. But there will be an occasional significant difference. And you won't be able to tell if that difference is important to you unless and until you have a strong understanding of your goals.

Comment: You also mention being an M$ shop... then Sharepoint and PowerPivot costs to acquire are probably next to nothing. Microstrategy could be a million bucks. (That's just from the observation that it seems nearly impossible to bring in a new vendor, into a enterprise setting for less than $1MM.

Comment: We kind of have an in with Microstrategy as well, so the costs may be manageable. I know it's the wrong way round but we often do things that way here :(. I pushing for Microstrategy at the moment but still interested in any thoughts about the other options.

Comment: Licensing isn't the only cost. There are supply chain costs for each new vendor you add. If your existing employees are M$ people, they are more than likely not Micro people too... so now you're hiring or training, but those are both costs.

Answer (score 2):

Sharepoint and Microstrategy do quite different things. Microstrategy is a BI solution whereas SharePoint is primarily a content management server. I think you need to pin down more precisely what your requirements are.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have SQL server 2008 standard or enterprise, then you already have SSAS, SSIS, SSRS -- it is all included in installation.

Thing to understand is that integration (SSIS) and Analytics (SSAS) services are independent applications which do not have to be installed together with SQL server. They are simply shipped as "added value" with the installation of the SQL server.

For example, you can install SSAS on your laptop and start data-mining today. You can also use SSAS and dimensional modelling to create cubes -- so called Microsoft data warehouse -- but you do not have to. You can build a data warehouse using plain Kimball or Inmon methodology, using a "standard" relational database.

If interested in data-mining, SSAS does not take much memory, and as most data-mining packages works best with flat tables. There is also an add-in for Excel, so you can do some mining directly from Excel -- need to have SSAS and the add-in installed.

Weka (Pentaho) is quite good for data mining and available as a freebie download - so you can try that.

In other words, you do have quite a few options to start data-mining, or building a DW without having to dish out extra M$.

For reports, you should already have report server (SSRS), and if you prefer open source, check out Pentaho and Jasper.

P.S. No matter what marketing people claim, Sharepoint has nothing to do with BI, really.

Comment: Would you say sharepoint was useful for accessing data from a dw and creating reports?

Comment: You can publish reports into the Sharepoint (content management system), but you can access reports directly from the report server. BI reports and DW do not need Sharepoint in any shape or form. But, you can if you wish and have nothing better to do.

Comment: Patrick... not a fan of SP here... but 2010 and powerpivot add a ton of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is no secret that when it comes to choosing the best Business Intelligence suite, it all depends on your requirements. Large number of BI suites is available in market with their individual pros and cons. As far as SharePoint is concerned, it is a Microsoft web application platform and not a BI tool. MicroStrategy is a US based company providing BI, mobile software and cloud based services. Their BI product offering is named as MicroStrategy Analytics Platform.

**Pros of using MicroStrategy BI platform include:**

- Powerful in schema and SQL design
- Stable platform
- Easy administration
- Secured platform

**Cons of using MicroStrategy BI platform include:**

- Slow development process
- Low on graphics
- Less community support